# "sqlite3.OperationalError: attempt to write a readonly database" even after chmod 777

Tags: django, docker, sqlite

I' m running a Django application within a docker container. I'm getting this error `sqlite3.OperationalError: attempt to write a readonly database`. I've tried everything in the Dockerfile

```
RUN chown username db.sqlite3
RUN chmod 777 db.sqlite3
```

I tried also to run the application as root user, but I still get the same error.

Here is my Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.9.5-alpine

RUN addgroup -S apigroup && adduser -S weatherapi -G apigroup

WORKDIR /app

ADD requirements.txt .

RUN apk update && apk upgrade

RUN python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip && python3 -m pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

COPY . . 

USER root
EXPOSE 8000
RUN chmod 777 db.sqlite3

USER weatherapi

RUN python3 manage.py migrate

CMD ["sh", "-c", "python3 manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000"]
```

And my docker-compose

```
version: '3.7'

networks: 
  weather_api_net:
    driver: bridge
    driver_opts:
      com.docker.network.enable_ipv6: "false"
    
services:
  web:
    restart: unless-stopped
    image: weatherapi:1.0
    container_name: weatherapi
    ports:
     - "8000:8000"
    volumes:
     - .:/app
    deploy:
      replicas: 1
      update_config:
        parallelism: 2
        delay: 10s
        order: start-first
      rollback_config:
          parallelism: 2
          delay: 10s
          failure_action: continue
          monitor: 60s
          order: stop-first
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure
    networks:
     - weather_api_net
```

Comment: can you please add your dockerfile and if any volumes mappings?

Comment: @umair I've added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just had to change the base image to a Debian based image.

```
FROM python:3.8-buster
```

Apparently Alpine doesn't like SQLite.